# Putting borders around the Headers and Footers sections

Tags: microsoft-excel, headers, border

I want to put borders around the three sections of the Headers and Footers
when I print an Excel workbook.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

### Update

As an example for the result, is the picture below which I prepared in MS-Paint:

[image]

I have a WorkSheet that has Header. **How can set borders around the Header's area, as shown in above picture?**

Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Please don't post images that are 90% blank.  And what does your last sentence mean?

Comment: With regards. That sentence means "How to solving the issue that pointed in above picture (with red points)?". Indeed I need the Right Header and Left Header having in order right Margin and left Margin and these headers values not crossing to their involving border.

Answer (score 0):

In the top row of your print area, change the row height to the height you want your "header".

In the first cell of each section on this header row, type the name of the header section.

Highlight the first cell with the header title and all the cells to the right to the end of the section.

In the home tab, Merge and Center the contents of this cell across the section.

In the home tab, in the font area, click on the border type "thick box border".

Repeat for the other header title of the other sections.

Comment: I want using `Page Setup> Header/ Footer` Option because: 1) `page: m of n` option. 2) Been more clear and invisible in the visible range area. With note that my Left Header Section is contains a logo picture which I want not be visible in the sheets range. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add a comment, so if my understanding is incorrect please let me know.

I think you can set the Range as Table first and create a `Table Style`, if this style will be used in different Workbooks you can Record the Table Style as a Macro.

For the Table Style you can format the **Whole Table** and **Header Row** as shown:

[image: Format Whole Table and Header Row]

Then you will get the result:

[image: RESULT]

Then print it.

Comment: Please view the above comment. Regards.